# How to find geo fence using Google maps API

Tags: google-maps, maps

If I search for a postal code on google maps, I get a red dotted geo fence polygon for an area. Is there any way to fetch a set of lat, long values for a postal/zip code area via an API using google maps?

The Geocode API gives only a northeast and southwest bound for a postal code, which is coarse. I need more lat long locations to actually construct a polygon for the required postal/zip code.

Is there any API from google maps that enables me to do this?

Comment: Your question is answered here:
[https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133492/zipcode-to-polygon-boundry](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133492/zipcode-to-polygon-boundry)